# Rest Webservices Exception return stack trace

Tags: rest

We have rest webservices using spring and cxf. When a checked exception is thrown we get the correct localized exception via soap ui.

But when a unchecked runtime exception is thrown we simply get a stack trace stating the webservice could not loaded.

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class WebServiceExceptionWrapper extends Exception {

    /** Type (class name). */
    private String type;

    /** Message. */
    private String message;

    /** Stack trace. */
    private StackTraceElement[] stackTrace;

    /** Cause. */
    private Throwable cause;

    /** The localized message. */
    private String localeErrorCode;

    /**
     * Construct a wrapper around an exception.
     * 
     * @param e exception
     */
    public WebServiceExceptionWrapper(final Exception e) {
        this.type = e.getClass().getName();
        this.message = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        this.stackTrace = e.getStackTrace();
        this.cause = e.getCause();
        if(e instanceof DetailedException) {
            this.localeErrorCode = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(((DetailedException) e).getLocaleErrorCode());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the type.
     * 
     * @return the type
     */
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the type.
     * 
     * @param type the type to set
     */
    public void setType(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the message.
     * 
     * @return the message
     */
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the message.
     * 
     * @param message the message to set
     */
    public void setMessage(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the stackTrace.
     * 
     * @return the stackTrace
     */
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public StackTraceElement[] getStackTrace() {
        return this.stackTrace;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the stackTrace.
     * 
     * @param stackTrace the stackTrace to set
     */
    public void setStackTrace(final StackTraceElement[] stackTrace) {
        this.stackTrace = stackTrace;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the cause.
     * 
     * @return the cause
     */
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public Throwable getCause() {
        return this.cause;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the cause.
     * 
     * @param cause the cause to set
     */
    public void setCause(final Throwable cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
    }

    /**
     * @return the localeErrorCode
     */
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public String getLocaleErrorCode() {
        return this.localeErrorCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param localeErrorCode the localeErrorCode to set
     */
    public void setLocaleErrorCode(final String localeErrorCode) {
        this.localeErrorCode = localeErrorCode;
    }
```

How I do prevent a stack trace from being returned. I just want a response code and a reponse message.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle exception flows in JAX-RS webservices using Apache-CXF is through the javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper class marked with an @Provider annotation (or in the Provider section of your jaxrs:server (jaxrs:providers). You can then trap specific exceptions that you want to return specific status codes for instance:

```
@Provider
public class FooExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<FooException>  {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(FooException exception) {
        ... do your work you want to maybe do here
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(...whatever...).build();
    }
}
```

Now you create a bean for this mapper (or use annotation driven), tie it to your service method, and then catch your exceptions. In your catch block simply throw this and let the interceptor framework of cxf take over.

Comment: what do you mean how do we deal with errors? The framework will handle anything you don't explicitly match by converting it to a 500, which is probably the most correct behavior.